# Ways of linking to a Custom Report

Tags: visualforce, reporting, custom-report-type

I've followed this blog http://www.interactiveties.com/b_dynamic_report_part1.php and managed to successfully achieve this, in a custom Visualforce page.

My problem now is, since the ID won't always be the same, finding a way of linking to the report without using the static ID. IS there any other way to link to the report through like, for example, an Unique Name?

Best regards

Comment: Which id? The report's id won't be changing. Can you expand on what exactly you're trying to do? Are you trying to dynamically choose which report to show in your VF page?

Comment: ID can change between orgs though.

Comment: you could store the ID or the Report URL in a custom setting which would then allow for great flexibility than hard coding the value into a query, this would also get around the ID changing when installed into different orgs.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem for when orgs change, what both Sdry and Michael Fleming said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query the Report table to find a report:

```
SELECT Id, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName 
FROM   Report 
WHERE  DeveloperName = 'My_Report' AND 
       NamespacePrefix = 'mypackageprefix'
```

Use the NamespacePrefix if you're in a managed package, otherwise you can skip it.

Comment: I've tried this and, with the help from your query example on Reports, it works now. Is this a "right way" of doing it? Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way of doing this.  @sfdcfox beat me to the punch once again ;-)  But, I was going to suggest this as well.

Comment: Just a side note - Report table appears empty by default in unit tests saved with API version > 23. You will need `@isTest(seeAllData=true)` to get code coverage for the part that relies on results of this query. Or some `Test.isRunningTest()`...